# Know the interface from the mac-address snmp

Tags: linux, snmp, mac-address, cisco

I have the Mac-Address of one host. I want to know to which interface this host is connected to the cisco switch.
I use snmp to do this work.

I want to create a script to do this.
So how can i do that? Should i know the vlan ?

Regards

Comment: There is the same question - [My anwer is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719357/snmp-oid-to-map-mac-addresses-to-ip-addresses/38257710#38257710)

Answer (score 0):

You need the following:

```
show ip arp <ip address>
show mac-address-table address <mac address>
show cdp neighbors <interface> detail
```

Enjoy

Comment: Just use TCL. http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/6_x/nx-os/fundamentals/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_7000_Series_NX-OS_Fundamentals_Configuration_Guide_Release_6.x_chapter_01001.pdf

Comment: I didn't understand how can i do that from my pc without opening the switch window using tcl !!